# Why does it print 012 not 123

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

For homework I have to create a node of multiple soldiers and print for n digits, ie 5, print 1 to 5 then 5 to 1

right now if n is 3 instead of 123 i get 012

I've tried fixing pointers and my for loop...

```
Spongebob* create_reverse_circle(int n)
{

   Spongebob *p= NULL;
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       //everytime a soldier is created, it goes in beg. of 
       push(&p,create_soldier(i));
   }
   printf("checkmate\n");
   return p;
}

void push(Spongebob **p, Spongebob* temp)
{
    if(*p==NULL)
    {
        temp->next = temp->prev = temp;
        *p = temp;
         return;
    }

    Spongebob *last = (*p)->prev;
    temp->next = *p;
    (*p)->prev = temp;
    temp->prev = last;
    last->next =temp;
}


Spongebob* rearrange_circle(Spongebob* head)
{
    Spongebob* temp = head;
    Spongebob* head2 = NULL;
    Spongebob* next = NULL;

    do
    {
        next = head->next;
        temp->next = head2->next;
        head2->next = temp;
        temp = head2->prev;
    }
    while(head!= NULL);

    if(temp != NULL ) 
        head2 = temp->prev; 

}
```

created spongebob0
created spongebob1
created spongebob2
checkmate
0 1 2

this is the output 
and i get a segmentation dump if I try my rearrange circle function

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What's a `Spongebob` when it's at home?  It probably isn't a yellow sponge.

Comment: In `rearrange_circle()`, `head2` is `NULL`, but you dereference it in the `do` `while` loop.

Comment: I would Suggest: Restarting from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem. Use simple, descriptive names for functions and variables – don’t copy the names you’re using in your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

> right now if n is 3 instead of 123 i get 012

I guess that depends on what `create_soldier(i)` does with the value in `i`, but note that the loop uses `i` values from 0 to n-1, not 1 to n.

Perhaps you should change the start and end values of the `for` loop to:

```
   for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
```

---

> i get a segmentation dump if I try my rearrange circle function

```
Spongebob* rearrange_circle(Spongebob* head)
{
    Spongebob* temp = head;
    Spongebob* head2 = NULL;
    Spongebob* next = NULL;

    do
    {
        next = head->next;
        temp->next = head2->next;
```

^^^ You are dereferencing a null pointer `head2`.

```
        head2->next = temp;
        temp = head2->prev;
    }
    while(head!= NULL);
```

^^^ `head!=NULL` will always be true (resulting in an infinite loop) unless `rearrange_circle()` was called with a null pointer (in which case, the previous `next = head->next;` is a null pointer dereference.

```
    if(temp != NULL ) 
        head2 = temp->prev;
```

^^^ This is at the end of the function, and `head2` is not used now, so the above statement seems a bit pointless.

```
}
```

I don't know what `rearrange_circle()` is supposed to do, so I have no suggestion how to fix it.

Comment: thank you so much, my 123 is fixed now. The rearrange circle should reverse the numbers 123 to 321